# POM to import JGraphT nio package

Tags: java, jgrapht

Trying to run the JGraphT [hello world](https://jgrapht.org/guide/HelloJGraphT) example, POM [per here](https://jgrapht.org/) looks like:

```
<groupId>org.jgrapht</groupId>
<artifactId>jgrapht-core</artifactId>
<version>1.4.0</version>
```

But this is not pulling down the org.jgrapht.nio.* it seems, file tree below:

[image]

What do I need in the POM to do these successfully:

```
import org.jgrapht.nio.*;
import org.jgrapht.nio.dot.DOTExporter;
```

Thanks

Comment: OK, got it here https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.jgrapht/jgrapht-io/1.4.0/jar

Answer (score 5):

For me, it works when I add this following dependency :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.jgrapht</groupId>
        <artifactId>jgrapht-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

in the pom.xml file.

After that, import the dependency in your file of code :

```
import org.jgrapht.nio.*;
```